# How to tell if a view has been created WITH CHECK OPTION in Sybase ASE

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

Is it possible to determine whether an existing view in Sybase ASE (v15.7) has the `WITH CHECK OPTION` clause?  I have created 2 views that are identical except for that clause, and the entries in all system tables (e.g. `sysobjects`, `syscomments`, `sysprotects` etc.) appear to be identical for both views.  `exec sp_helptext` does not show the clause.

In MSSQL, [sys.views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190334.aspx) has a `with_check_option` column, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for ASE.

In the example below, the `WITH CHECK OPTION` clause works exactly as expected, i.e. an insert into `check_test_2` fails unless `visible` is set to `Y`.  Is there any way to determine which of the views has the `WITH CHECK OPTION` clause set?

Example code:

```
use tempdb
go

if object_id('check_test') is not null drop table check_test
go
create table check_test (id int, visible char(1))
go

if object_id('check_test_1') is not null drop view check_test_1
go
create view check_test_1
as
select *
from check_test
where visible = 'Y'
go

if object_id('check_test_2') is not null drop view check_test_2
go
create view check_test_2
as
select *
from check_test
where visible = 'Y'
with check option
go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug in Sybase ASE from 12.5 up to 16.0, but may be released in certain service packs (16.0 SP01, 15.7 SP134 - not yet confirmed).

http://scn.sap.com/thread/3713912

The solution is to set some switches (200 = print tree before optimization, 3604 = print output to client), then `select` from the view, and search in the output for `CHECKOPT`, so for the example from the question:

```
use tempdb
go
set switch on 200
set switch on 3604
set noexec on
go
select *
from check_test_2
go
```

Somewhere in the (rather large) output will be:

```
... root2stat:(0x10000000 (BCP_LABELS, CHECKOPT)) ...
```